# Looking for Explanation of pointer initializing to const int and int

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, constants, constexpr

I was working through exercises in C++ Primer and found online solutions for Exercise 2.32.

I understood that the following code was illegal because initializing can't convert from int to int*:

`int null = 0, *p = null;`

However, two of the solutions that were mentioned, that I did not come up with were:

```
    const int null3 = 0, *p3 = null3;
    
    constexpr int null4 = 0, *p4 = null4;
```

How come it allows these during compile without error? I was still expecting the initialize of p3 and p4 to require the & to denote address (&null3, &null4).

Here is the code I have from my notepad file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

//  int null = 0, *p = null; // it is not legal; depending on intent there are two ways to fix (that I can think off atm)

    {
    int null = 0, *p = &null; // if the goal is to point to 'null'
    }
    {
    int null2 = 0, *p2 = 0; // if the goal is to create a nullptr
    }
    {
    const int null3 = 0, *p3 = null3; // if the goal is to create a nullptr
    }
    {
    constexpr int null4 = 0, *p4 = null4; // if the goal is to create a nullptr
    }

return 0;
}
```

When I run via Microsoft Visual Studio CMDPrompt it allows me to 'cl "Exercise 2.32.cpp"' without error.

Comment: ```const int null3 = 0, *p3 = null3;``` this still gives error are you sure it is getting compiled?

Comment: without error? I didn't find a compiler that accepts it: https://godbolt.org/z/aK1Gvz. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @D'Kayd: That should not compile.

Comment: absolutely @Bathsheba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is one way of denoting a *null pointer constant*. (It's an integer type that evaluates to zero.) In other words it is a special case and you are allowed to assign a pointer type to it.

A standards compliant compiler should issue a diagnostic for the assignments of a pointer type to `null3` and `null4`. (It should also issue a diagnostic for `int *p = +0;`.) If yours doesn't then check appropriate compiler flags are set.

Using `nullptr` is far better though:

```
int *p = nullptr;
```

Comment: "assign a pointer type to `null3`" I always get confused with this so it might be my limited english, but isn't it the other way around? "assing `null3` to a pointer" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818: You can say either. English is wicked in that way. Rather like C++!

Comment: in that case I prefer C++

Comment: How so? AFAIK literal 0 can be used as null pointer for backward compatibility in C++ but not constant int variable with value 0 and not constant int expression like 1 - 1.

Comment: The rules for null pointer constants were tightened in C++11; previous versions allowed any constant expression rvalue of value 0, so `+` can *allow* usage.

Comment: @Bathsheba So if I'm understanding correctly, you're saying this is specifically because in the examples const and constexpr are resulting in `0` that this is a special case?

Comment: @Bathsheba Ok, I just tried again and changed the `null3` and `null4` value from `0` to `1` and I got the compile errors.